# Selecting the row in a Pandas dataframe if the value is a float

Tags: python, pandas

```py
def categorizeMainUrl(url):
    category = "other"
    if "/special/" in url:
        category = "special"
    return category
df["category"] = df["main_URL"].apply(lambda url: categorizeMainUrl(url))
```

While running this part of the code, I keep the following exception.
`"TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable"`
How can I select only the section of the dataframe with the float values?
(In this column, I would wait only string as a datatype)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to fill `NaN` values, then you can use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) 
to create a new serie:

```
df["category"] = np.where(df['main_URL'].fillna('').str.contains('/special/'),
                          "special", "other")
```

or

```
df["category"] = (df['main_URL'].fillna('')
                                .str.contains('/special/')
                                .map({True:"special",
                                      False:"other"}) 
                 )
#df['main_URL'].fillna('').str.contains('/special/').replace({True:"special",
#                                                              False:"other"})
```

---

I recommend you see: [`when should I want to use apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code)

Answer (score 0):

The following command select only the rows containing on specific datatype (here float):
`df[df["category"].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, float))]`

Comment: this solutoon works but surely inefficient,I recommend you see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code